# Building Tile in XAML

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I am trying to add a tile in via XAML. I eventually want to add text to the tiles, such as news articles (so a news article for each tile in my mainpage.xaml). Can anyone point me to an example or show me a code snippet as to how this can be accomplished? I will post a screenshot of what I am trying to accomplish....

[image]

This is a code snippet I found online, but looks like it is for Windows 8 development?

```
<controls:Tile Title="Hello!" 
   TiltFactor="2"
   Width="100" Height="100" 
   Count="1">
</controls:Tile>
```

NOTE: This is a **Universal Windows Application**

Comment: I am wanting tiles in the app... Like the first page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the GridView in xaml (exists both in W8 and UWP)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx

You can define an `ItemContainterStyle` such that it will look like your tiles.

An example, with some hardcoded items:

```
<GridView Width="800" Height="300">
  <GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </GridView.ItemsPanel>
  <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
      <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
              <Grid Background="Gray" Margin="5" Height="100" Width="100">
                <ContentPresenter />
              </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style.Setters> 
    </Style>
  </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>

  <GridViewItem>
    Item1
  </GridViewItem>
  <GridViewItem>
    Item2
  </GridViewItem>
  <GridViewItem>
    Item3
  </GridViewItem>
  <GridViewItem>
    Item4
  </GridViewItem>
  <GridViewItem>
    Item5
  </GridViewItem>
  <GridViewItem>
    Item6
  </GridViewItem>
  <GridViewItem>
    Item7
  </GridViewItem>
  <GridViewItem>
    Item8
  </GridViewItem>
</GridView>
```

This will look like:

[image]

If you want to bind your ItemsSource to your VM, you can do so as such.
Assuming the property `public ObservableCollection<string> Items {get;set;}` exists in your VM.

Replace `<GridView Width="800" Height="300">` with `<GridView Width="800" Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">`

Comment: Am I able to dynamically set the values of the text in those tiles using this method?

Comment: Yes you can. You'll have to bind the ´GridView´'s ´ItemSource´ to an ´ObservableCollection´ that contains the texts.

Comment: So is each gridview a tile?

Comment: And sorry, I have pasted the above code snippet into my project trying to reproduce your image... I am not able to reproduce it? Can you provide a little more code to get me started?

Comment: @Code, I've updated my post with the complete example (I didn't post any GridViewItems in the above sample. + Explained how to bind to it.

Comment: @Code, each tile is represented by one GridViewItem inside the GridView

Comment: Ok, I see what this is doing.. is there a way to make these tiles responsive for when the window size changes?

Comment: They'll wrap depending on the height and width of the GridView, if you remove its restrictions (I've set them to a hardcoded value in the sample above), it'll work. When you change the window size, they'll wrap onto the next column.

Comment: Understood.... This may be off topic, but is there a way to make the tiles different sizes? And them all not be the same size?

Comment: If you want all of them on the same size, just change the GridViewItems size (look for the inner Grid). For different sizes, look up the VariableSizedGridView :)